# Android OS certificate pinning

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, pinning

I will start with a very very short introduction on OS certificate pinning for Android. Starting with version 4.2 of Android system/OS level SSL/TLS certificate pinning was introduced (see also this URL for more info.). The list of pinned certificates using this mechanism is located at: **"/data/misc/keychain/pins"** and contains by default around 40 entries for Google services like mail.google.com, youtube.com, etc. I would very much like to have my own certificate pinned by having it added to this list. However, modifying this list requires an Android permission (`android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS`) that's only available to system apps.

Doe anyone know if there might by some kind procedure in place at Google to submit a request to be added to this list (i.e. /data/misc/keychain/pins)?

Comment: why do you want to edit the list if you can just make SSLHandshake?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve. If you want that your app pins on a specific certificate you do not have to add your certificate to the os. You can handle that in the HTTP-component of your app.

Comment: For the app I am forced to use a WebView. Unfortunately from the WebView you are not able to control the HTTP connections. If a user clicks on a link/button on the WebView I want to be sure that the connection is secured, and not intercepted/modified. Native code will not help me here.

Answer (score 0):

WebViews are tricky, not least because there is no perfect way to implement pinning in them except with Android N using [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning).

The best you can do is override `shouldInterceptRequest` and implement the network calls yourself using one of the methods described in [Android Security: SSL Pinning](https://appmattus.medium.com/android-security-ssl-pinning-1db8acb6621e), however this only intercepts GET requests so if your WebViews use POST requests then you are out of luck. [Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews](https://github.com/menjoo/Android-SSL-Pinning-WebViews/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mennomorsink/webview/SecureWebViewClient.kt) shows an example of doing this.